# category page design issue

Tags: html, css, wordpress

i am using maximus theme .this is my site category page **[Category](http://www.trackschoolbus.com/for-schools/)** . I have changed the layout with some css tweeks . an i got the way i wanted . but the thrid post itrem is aligned to left . then the next two display correct again third goes to the right.i know this is not the right way .. but as for time being i would like to make it work like this
 i have no idea what is the issue .

this the css i have given

```
.category .span12 .row-fluid:nth-of-type(2),
.category .span12 .row-fluid:first-child {
    width:100% !important;
    float:left;
}

.category .span9 .row-fluid {
    width:47% !important;
    float:left;
    padding-left: 10px;
}

.category .blog-content {
    display:none;
}
```

please help

Comment: You need to specify height of each article element, so they are seen as proper block elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The height of your content blocks is different. Because the first block is bigger then the second is is seeing that there is space earlier on the page on the right side. Where it will place your block.

You could solve this in several ways.

- Just simply give a standard height to all of your blocks.

for Example:

```
.category .span9 .row-fluid {
    float: left;
    min-height: 195px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    width: 45% !important;
}
```

- Use a (pinterest like) masonry javascript: http://masonry.desandro.com/
- Calculate the height of your items (per couple) in javascript. And give them both the height of the biggest block.

Hope this solves your problem.

Answer (score 1):

it works

```
.category .span9 .row-fluid {
    float: left;
    min-height: 195px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    width: 45 % !important;
}
```

Comment: editted my answer with your example :) So we have a complete answer. Hope you don't mind :)